# Find the closest matching row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following table.

```
TableName: Mask

Columns:

MaskId INT
MaskCode VARCHAR(100)
```

If I pass Input as MaskId=1 then I am getting
two records with different maskcodes.

```
select maskcode from mask where maskid=1

G******
G12****
```

I want to find the closest matching row among these two rows. I am going to introduce one more 
input @Maskcode

Scenario-1:

Now I am going to pass two inputs

```
MaskId=1, maskcode=G123456
```

My query would be something like this

```
select maskcode from mask where maskid=1 and maskcode='G123456'
```

In this case I need G12**** row because this is the closest match among the two rows.

Scenario-2:

```
MaskId=1, maskcode=G999999
```

In this case I need G***** row.

Scenario-3:

For MaskId=2 I have two records below

```
6h****
6h****
```

My input for this case would be Maskid=2 and Maskcode=6h1234
I need two rows in this case since we cannot find the most closest in these two.

I tried the below but it returns two rows.

```
select *From mask
where @Maskcode
like '%'+replace(MaskCode,'*',''+'%'
```

Please provide any ideas.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if the answers below worked for you, I'd accept one of them :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `TOP` and `LEN` and `LIKE`:

```
select top 1 m.*
from mask
where @Maskcode like '%' + replace(MaskCode, '*', '') + '%'
order by len(replace(MaskCode, '*', '')) desc;
```

By the way, do you really want the wildcard at the beginning?  Or perhaps you want:

```
where @Maskcode like replace(MaskCode, '*', '%')
```

Multiple occurrences of `%` next to each other will not affect the `LIKE` pattern semantics.

Comment: I can't use top since for some cases I need multiple rows. I updated my question. Please check how to achieve scenario-3 as well

Comment: @StackUser . . . Of course you can.  Just use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @MaskCode varchar(25) = '6h1234'

Select * 
 From  (
        Select *,Rnk = Dense_Rank() over (Order By Len(Replace(MaskCode,'*','')) Desc)
         From  MaskCode
         Where @MaskCode Like Replace(MaskCode,'*','')+'%'
       ) A
 Where Rnk=1
```

With @MaskCode = '6h1234' Returns

```
MaskID  MaskCode    Rnk
2       6h****      1
2       6h****      1
```

With @MaskCode = 'G123456' Returns

```
MaskID  MaskCode    Rnk
1       G12****     1
```